# How can I do tree shaking for Chakra UI in NextJS?

Tags: next.js, chakra-ui, tree-shaking

I write the code as shown in the documentation:

```
import {Box} from '@chakra-ui/react';
```

But when I run build, my page imports the entire library instead of one component.
I found a post where a user says this works with webpack5
https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/discussions/2291

[image]

But in the latest updates NextJS switched to SWC, I tried to turn it off by reverting to .babelrc, but I still can't get the result of tree-shaking.

Comment: please share some additional information like `source code` and `what you want to achieve`

Comment: Do you have `webpack.config.js` in your project

Comment: @Zain_Ul_Din No, I install the project with `npx create-next-app`

Comment: sorry I'm not sure how to fix it. I think you cloud use `tailwind CSS` although it is lightweight and easy to use and `chakra UI` is also built on the top of `tailwind CSS`